# Screencast from Google Glass

Tags: android, video-streaming, google-glass

I'm looking for an efficient way to stream what Google Glass's camera is seeing in real time. I know there're several alternatives, including [MyGlass](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3068035?hl=en), but I'd like to build my own app since it will have several extra features.

My first approach was to just send frame by frame to the server, letting server side to compose the video, but I'm guessing there must be a more efficient approach. Anyone who can point me in the right direction to a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

MyGlass does not deliver live video casting, nothing even close to this. I have easily built an RTSP streaming app around the wonderful [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) library, which has recently been updated to support Google Glass. Worked smoothly (but with some lag) over WiFi at 320x240 resolution with H264 codec.

Comment: You're right @AlexCohn, I misunderstood the concepts. Found `libstreaming` yesterday, it looks pretty promising indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, have you implemented server side as well? Or used VLC/MediaPlayer or similar instead?

Comment: I used VLC for this POC.

Comment: @AlexCohn can you please list out the steps, that would be really helpful, trying something similar with glass...any direction on this would be just awesome..

Answer (score 1):

See this example for generically doing this in android: http://www.mattakis.com/blog/kisg/20090708/broadcasting-video-with-android-without-writing-to-the-file-system

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.